# Cannot use particular pin in GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio, c

I am trying to blink a LED on a Raspberry Pi using GPIO 4 (P1.7). Here is my code:

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_7

int main()
{
    bcm2835_init();

    bcm2835_gpio_fsel (PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

    while (1)
    {
        bcm2835_gpio_write(PIN, HIGH);
        bcm2835_delay(1000);
        bcm2835_gpio_write(PIN, LOW);
        bcm2835_delay(1000);
    }
    bcm2835_close();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is when I build this code I got this error:

```
ledblinking.c: In function ‘main’:
ledblinking.c:9:19: error: ‘RPI_GPIO_P1_7’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ledblinking.c:9:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I have tried to replace this line:

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_7
```

... With this:

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_11
```

I mean to use P1.11 in place of P1.7 (which works). So, can any one tell me why I cannot use P1.7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should replace

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_7
```

with

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_07
```

(see the '0' before '7' ?)